# Setting Inherited Attributes of a Child Instance from a database of Parent Class instances (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, oop

How do I set values of the inherited attributes of the Parent class to the child from an instance of the Parent class?

I have a database of the instances of the parent class, which I loop over in a method of the Child to find the appropriate instance by name. I would then like to set all inherited values of the instance to those of the instance that was found by the loop.

```
class Material:
    name = None     
    rho = 1.0       #density (kg/m^3)
    E = 1.0e06      #elasticMod (kPa)
    poisson = 0.01  #poisson's ratio (n/a)
    sY = 1.0e06     #yieldStrength (kPa)
    sUT = 1.0e06    #ultimateTensileStrength (kPa)
    CoF = 0.10      #coefficient of Friction (n/a)

    matLib = [] # material Library

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
            Material.matLib.append(self.name) #add to the library

class component(Material):

    mass = None  # Piston Mass (g)
    mat = None    # Material !!! keyWord to find values !!!
    ...(etc)...
...

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def setMat(self):
        for n in Material.matLib:
            if self.mat is in Material.matLib:   
                self.rho =  <found_instance_value.rho>      #kg/m^3
                E = <found_instance_value.E>  ...(etc)...

...

aisi4340 = Material(name='aisi4340',
                    rho = 7850,
                    E = 8.0E06,
                    sY = 4.70e07,
                    sUT = 7.45e07,
                    poisson = 0.29
                   ) 


Piston = component(
                   geom = path + '.stp'
                   mat = 'aisi4340'
                   ...(etc)...
                  )

Piston.setMat()

... do some calcs on this component, 
    but other components are made of other materials,
    which should also inherit their respective values
```

Comment: You are mixing *encapsulation* with *inheritance*. Your `component` instances are *also* `Material` instances and have the same attributes and methods. But your `component` *also* stores a `Material` instance as an attribute? That's sometimes a valid technique, but I doubt that that is what you wanted to do *here*.

Comment: Pick one or the other here. Either the `Component` class is *not* a material but has a `.material` attribute referencing an existing `Material` instance, *or* `Component` instances are a special kind of `Material`.

Comment: If you pick the latter, you can just *pass in* the material on creation (`Component(..., material=aisi4340, ...), no need to use `setMat()` calls, and reference `piston.material.<attribute>` or use `__getattr__` to proxy attribute lookups.

Comment: The material library should be a global dict outside the classes. `if self.name not in matLib: matLib[self.name] = self` 

You can do the material instance lookup in `Component` based on the material name and set `self.material` to that.

Comment: A few comments: 1) The attribute values for Piston are actually contained in a separate input file that is read in. How would what Martijn is suggesting work in that case?    2) riddler can you describe in more detail what you mean?